# pgfplots, multiply values, add ticks without numbers

Tags: pgfplots, ticks

I am new to Latex and want to add some plots with pgfplots. I want to make musical tempo graphs. So the x-axis indicates the respective beat and the y-axis indicates the bpm value.

1. I need a tick for every beat, but not a number, because the numbers would overlap.
2. I need to multiply the values of the y-axis with 6, because I need other values for it (bpm shouldn't relate to the whole 6/8-beat, but just an eigth note.) (The values are in a seperate file.)
3. I want a fixed value area for the y-axis, for example, from 150 to 300 to compare different of those graphs of the same type.

(I just can't manage to provide a working code example, but in my document the graph is just compiled right. The attached section shows three coordinate lists, but I only need the former two.)

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}%

\begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            width=\textwidth,
            height=5cm,
            xlabel={$Taktzahl$},
            ylabel={$Tempo~in~bpm$},
            ]
            \addplot [black] table {Daten/0S.txt};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Tempodiagramm}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Contents of the seperate document:

```
22  21.6346 17.1
23  25.8325 17.2
24  29.3521 17.3
25  28.6512 17.4
26  22.7039 18.1
27  18.4983 18.2
28  26.4515 18.3
29  34.6263 18.4
30  23.0456 19.1
31  33.7776 19.2
32  38.8204 19.3
33  43.3373 19.4
34  44.0296 20.1
35  41.6352 20.2
36  26.5024 20.3
37  28.5326 20.4
```

Comment: Please have a look at the tour for beginners: https://tex.stackexchange.com/tour. You can accept the provided answer if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `ymin=150`, some of your data is outside the scale

```
\begin{filecontents}{data.txt}
22  21.6346 17.1
23  25.8325 17.2
24  29.3521 17.3
25  28.6512 17.4
26  22.7039 18.1
27  18.4983 18.2
28  26.4515 18.3
29  34.6263 18.4
30  23.0456 19.1
31  33.7776 19.2
32  38.8204 19.3
33  43.3373 19.4
34  44.0296 20.1
35  41.6352 20.2
36  26.5024 20.3
37  28.5326 20.4
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
width=\textwidth,
height=5cm,
xlabel={$Taktzahl$},
ylabel={$Tempo~in~bpm$},
xticklabels=\empty,
xtick distance=1,
ymin=150, ymax=300,
]
\addplot[black] table[y expr={6*\thisrowno{1}}] {data.txt};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Graph]

Comment: Thank you very much. This helps me out a lot. What should I write when I don't want that thexticklabels=\empty, but that just each fifth number is shown, but all of the ticks

Comment: Try to remove `xticklabels=\empty,` and insert `xtick distance=5,
minor x tick num=4,`

Comment: Thank's, it works!